# ( panzoom ) How to stop Image from panning out of the view?

Tags: javascript, panzoom

is there a way other than resetting the zoom to force image not to get lost completely while panning using [Panzoom library](https://github.com/anvaka/panzoom)

```js
const element = document.querySelector('#scene');

const zoomLevels = [0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.5, 3];
let currentZoomLevel = zoomLevels[4];
const text = document.querySelector('#text');

let panZoomController = panzoom(element);
```

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid red
}

img {
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/panzoom@8.1.0/dist/panzoom.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>
    <img id="scene" src="https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/5-1.png">
  </div>

  <br/>
<span>Image should not be Dragged /panned out of the view</span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is bounds property

```js
const element = document.querySelector('#scene');

const zoomLevels = [0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.5, 3];
let currentZoomLevel = zoomLevels[4];
const text = document.querySelector('#text');

let panZoomController = panzoom(element, {
  bounds: true,
  boundsPadding: 0.1
});
```

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid red
}

img {
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/panzoom@8.1.0/dist/panzoom.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>
    <img id="scene" src="https://www.probytes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/5-1.png">
  </div>

  <br/>
  <span>Image should not be Dragged /panned out of the view</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Am I the only one in 2023 that this does not work for? According to this 2020 comment: 
https://github.com/anvaka/panzoom/issues/112#issuecomment-654183558

it seems to have been broken back then already

Comment: EDIT:
setting `boundsPadding: 1` worked for me.

it is 0.05 by default which seems like a very unstandard use case

Answer (score 3):

```
let panZoomController = panzoom(element, {
  bounds: true,
  boundsPadding: 1
});
```